# Cannot centre the text in my menu

Tags: html, css

hi i'm new to coding and struggle to make my menu text centred. Please see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/64pu8axf/3/

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav">{menu}</div>
</div>

#nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 89.77%;
    left: 0 20;
    padding: 7px 0;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 5 ;
    background: #B31717;

#nav {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#nav > ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: please can you add the rendered menu html and be more precise about what you want aligning in the center - the whole menu?  Also is this vertically centered or horizontally centered and can you add your styles for `#nav > ul`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `text-align:center` to your `#nav-wrapper` should do the trick.

You are also missing a closing `}` for `#nav-wrapper`

Take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/68s4su8s/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav">{menu}</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 89.77%;
    left: 0 20;
    padding: 7px 0;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 5 ;
    background: #B31717;
    text-align:center; /* <---- Note the change */
} /* <---- Added missing closing } */
#nav {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#nav > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `}` for `#nav-wrapper`.
Add `text-align: center;` to `#nav`

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<div id="nav">menu</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 89.77%;
    left: 0 20;
    padding: 7px 0;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 5 ;
    background: #B31717;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav {
  vertical-align: center;
}

#nav > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Demo Link : https://jsfiddle.net/hellosrini/64pu8axf/9/